# What is the significance of "compact" in Lusin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem

For an interval $[a, b]$, let
${\displaystyle f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb {C} }$
be a measurable function. Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact $E \subset [a, b]$ such that f restricted to E is continuous and
${\displaystyle \mu (E)>b-a-\varepsilon .\,}$

I am pondering what is the significance of having a compact $E$? The result still holds for open $E$?

Is it so that $f_E$ is continuous on compact set $E$, hence uniformly continuous? Any other reasons for having compact $E$?

Comment: AFAICT it does not hold for open $E$. Is the characteristic function $f$ of $[a,b]\cap\Bbb{Q}$ not a counterexample? The restriction of $f$ to an open subset of $[a,b]$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $ f:[a,b] \to {\mathbb R} $ defined by $f(x)=1$ for $x\in{\mathbb Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ else.

Let (r_n)_n be a numbering of the rational numbers. For a given
$\epsilon>0$ set $$U_n = \left(r_n-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+2}}, r_n+\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+2}}\right)\cap [a,b].$$ 
The union of the $U_n$ contains all points from ${\mathbb Q}\cap [a,b]$, it is an open subset of $[a,b]$ and it has measure smaller than $\epsilon$.
Its complement $E$ is the compact subset whose existence is postulated by Lusin's theorem: $f\mid_E$ vanishes identically, so is clearly continuous.

On the other hand, you will obviously not find any open set on which $f$ is continuous. Any open neighborhood of any point contains both, points with$f(x)=0$ and points with $f(x)=1$.